# Setting Button ID programmatically

Tags: android, button

Android 2.3.3

I have a table with N rows and N columns. For each row, I should add 4 buttons dynamically, and later do actions based on the button clicked. I know we can set the button IDs with Integer values with `button.setID()`, but I want to know whether we can set IDs as string values as we set in XML files, such as `btnXYZ1` and `btnXYZ2` etc.,

Comment: The xml files don't set it as string. all Ids are converted into R.id , which has them all as integers.

Comment: Yeah i know, I was asking, whether we can do the same programatically.

Comment: Well if you have the reference for each of the buttons anyway , you can put them all in a HashMap<String,View> .

Comment: Ok, i will try the approach... Thanks for the help!!!

Comment: Maybe i should have posted an answer so that you could mark it. May I ?

Comment: Yeah please, I will try the approach and will select the best possible answer, as i always do...

Comment: Posted . also added another similar approach.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use tags for that purpose . For example

```
btn.setTag("btXYZ");
```

Comment: Ok, So, you mean, I set the IDs with integers and set the tags with strings and use the tags to find which button is clicked at a later stage?

Comment: Yes you can do it like that

Comment: @VamsiChalla All the functions you have to get a view using id are there for tags as well such as `findViewByTag` instead of `findViewById`, View.getTag() instead of getId() and ofcourse View.setTag

Answer (score 4):

```
for (int i=0;i<nob;i++) {
     Button btn = new Button(this);
     btn.setId(i+1);
     btn.setText("Button"+(i+1));
     btn.setOnClickListener(btnclick); <<<<<<<set click
     btn.setLayoutParams(lprams);
     dynamicview.addView(btn);
}
```

And add this listner outside the any method and inside class

```
OnClickListener btnclick = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        switch(view.getId()) {
            case 1:
                //first button click
                break;
                //Second button click
            case 2:
                break;
            case 3:
                //third button click
                break;
            case 4:
                //fourth button click
                break;
             .
             .
             .
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

The strings you use in your XML files correspond to an int in R.java, and are hence actually ints. The setId() method will only accept an int value as an argument. You could define your IDs in a constants file, something like:

```
public class Ids {
    public static final int ID_ONE = 1;
}
```

and then use it as:

```
button.setId(Ids.ID_ONE);
```

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot set it to `String`, the id is `int` value, even when you set it from `XML` it is just the resource name of an `int` value

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot set it to String, the id is int value, even when you set it from XML it is just the resource name of an int value

Answer (score 0):

If you have the references to the views anyway , you can simply save them all into a HashMap, for example using HashMap .

Another alternative , so that you will avoid any typos , is to have an enum as the key of the hashMap , for example : HashMap .